# Variables in directive isolate scope not available

Tags: angularjs

I'm experiencing some strange results in my code. For example, when you comment out the isolate scope line (`scope: {local:'='}`), the directive's scope has a local value, yet when you link the two, the local value is clearly sent to the parent scope, yet its deleted in the directive scope?

http://plnkr.co/edit/uBkCmnRQoj4B539nAkeW?p=preview

```
angular.module('My', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.parent = 2;
  })
  .directive('directive', function(){
    return {
      scope: { local: "=" }, // comment out this line... wtf?
      link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl){
        scope.local = 88;
        scope.doIt = function(){
          scope.local = 77;
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

and

```
  <body ng-app="My">
    <div class="ctrl" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <h3>ctrl</h3>
      parent: {{parent}}
      <div directive local="parent" class="directive">
        <h3>directive</h3>
        <div>local: {{local}}</div>
        <button ng-click="doIt()">click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Also, the ng-click="doIt()" doesn't seem to fire at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not of scope but of how your using the scope variables in your HTML.

By default, the directive's scope is not available in the HTML nested inside of it. You could use transclusion but often times a template is used for what you're doing in the Plunker:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: { local: "=" }, // comment out this line... wtf?
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl){
      scope.local = 88;
      scope.doIt = function(){
        scope.local = 77;
      };
    },
    template: '<h3>directive</h3><div>local: {{local}}</div><button ng-click="doIt()">click</button>'
  }
})
```

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ydmlw9XAS9G5PjrrczuF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases here.

1. When you uncomment the scope portion you get two scopes in your application. One scope is controller scope (`ctrl`), and second one is scope of div which uses your custom directive. They are completely separate and share no data inherently. Custom directive scope does take value from parent scope, because you set it explicitly (`scope: { local: "=" }`, `local="parent"`). When you set `local` to new value in child, isolated scope, it will also be copied back to original field (`parent`) because you specified so (`local: "="`). If you only want local to be set, then tell Angular not to copy value from isolated scope back to parent scope (do this by using `@` instead of `=`; `scope: { local: "@" }`)
   `ngClick` directive also doesn't work, because as we said, your custom directive scope is isolated. When you add `doIt` there, it's not available in controller scope.
2. When you comment `scope: { local: "=" }` portion, now your controller and custom directive share same scope. Now `doIt` function is available.

Comment: Of course, all of this is true and helpful, but I think the primary problem was that he was expecting the HTML nested inside of his directive to behave as if it were inserted into the directive as a template.